# Where is the entry point specified in angular application

Tags: angular, angular-cli, package.json

I'm new in angular and got sample angular application installed using angular-cli. This has package.json file, which must usually have the entry point of that application. But I didnt find that being defined in this pre-defined pakage.json file. Where does the entry point of angular app gets specified in this and why not in package.json file as expected.

Comment: Because it isn't a node script that you run. The entry point can be found in `main.ts`, unde the line `platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Angular does not provide an entry point similar to `node.js`, but rather a compiled application (a bunch of .js files, .css files, assets and an index.html file). The application can be run by opening the `index.html` file.

What parts of the application will be compiled is being determined by your `main.ts` file, and mostly the line

```
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
```

which defines the AppModule to be the "entry point" of your application.

> It is the "root" module that you bootstrap to launch the application

Please see [this documentation](https://angular.io/guide/bootstrapping) for further details.

Answer (score 4):

`main.ts  >>   app.Module.ts  >>  app.component.ts  >>  index.html  >>  app.component.html`

is the starting point in angular app
You can refer [here](https://www.javatpoint.com/how-an-angular-app-get-loaded-and-started).

Answer (score 2):

Angular and node.js are different altogether. Angular has is own way managing project structure

When Angular project is loaded ... it bootstraps the module defined in main.ts ... which is your AppModule.

```
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

Also, note that you are working with TypeScript files. Those files are transpiled to JavaScript and then compiled by the Angular compiler.

Answer (score 0):

As righlty mentioned in the other answers, the below line is the entry point of the Angular application.

```
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
```

and If you see AppModule, It has a line `bootstrap: [AppComponent]` which tells us the bootstrapping component is the `AppComponent`